# Laravel Breeze 2fa challange not showing up

Tags: laravel, fortify

I kind of set up Laravel with breeze and then i decided to install 2fa so i installed fortify. It seems that some routes are not working as expected and i just can't figure what it is. After the user activates 2fa i can see the QR code and the verificatin codes. Also i can see that the data is populated in the database like the "two_factor_secret" and "Two_factor_recovery_codes".  After i log out and try to log in again it just redirects me to the homepage but doesnt return for the 2fa challange view.

As said on this thread: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/305 i copied the "app/Http/Controllers/Auth/AuthenticatedSessionController.php" into my Controller and now the QR code is working but the user wont redirect to the 2fa challange screen after log in.

This is the AuthenticatedSessionController.php file:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Routing\Controller;
use Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\AttemptToAuthenticate;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\CanonicalizeUsername;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\PrepareAuthenticatedSession;
use Laravel\Fortify\Actions\RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse;
use Laravel\Fortify\Features;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;
use Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest;

class AuthenticatedSessionController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * The guard implementation.
     *
     * @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard
     */
    protected $guard;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\StatefulGuard  $guard
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(StatefulGuard $guard)
    {
        $this->guard = $guard;
    }

    /**
     * Show the login view.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LoginViewResponse
     */
    public function create(Request $request): LoginViewResponse
    {
        return app(LoginViewResponse::class);
    }

    /**
     * Attempt to authenticate a new session.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function store(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        return $this->loginPipeline($request)->then(function ($request) {
            return app(LoginResponse::class);
        });
    }

    /**
     * Get the authentication pipeline instance.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Fortify\Http\Requests\LoginRequest  $request
     * @return \Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline
     */
    protected function loginPipeline(LoginRequest $request)
    {
        if (Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback) {
            return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                call_user_func(Fortify::$authenticateThroughCallback, $request)
            ));
        }

        if (is_array(config('fortify.pipelines.login'))) {
            return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter(
                config('fortify.pipelines.login')
            ));
        }

        return (new Pipeline(app()))->send($request)->through(array_filter([
            config('fortify.limiters.login') ? null : EnsureLoginIsNotThrottled::class,
            config('fortify.lowercase_usernames') ? CanonicalizeUsername::class : null,
            Features::enabled(Features::twoFactorAuthentication()) ? RedirectIfTwoFactorAuthenticatable::class : null,
            AttemptToAuthenticate::class,
            PrepareAuthenticatedSession::class,
        ]));
    }

    /**
     * Destroy an authenticated session.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return \Laravel\Fortify\Contracts\LogoutResponse
     */
    public function destroy(Request $request): LogoutResponse
    {
        $this->guard->logout();

        if ($request->hasSession()) {
            $request->session()->invalidate();
            $request->session()->regenerateToken();
        }

        return app(LogoutResponse::class);
    }
}
```

I also have a set up a challange view and it seems that the routes in fortify my service provider file is correct like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Actions\Fortify\CreateNewUser;
use App\Actions\Fortify\ResetUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserPassword;
use App\Actions\Fortify\UpdateUserProfileInformation;
use Illuminate\Cache\RateLimiting\Limit;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\RateLimiter;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Laravel\Fortify\Fortify;

class FortifyServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Register any application services.
     */
    public function register(): void
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Bootstrap any application services.
     */
    public function boot(): void
    {
        Fortify::createUsersUsing(CreateNewUser::class);
        Fortify::updateUserProfileInformationUsing(UpdateUserProfileInformation::class);
        Fortify::updateUserPasswordsUsing(UpdateUserPassword::class);
        Fortify::resetUserPasswordsUsing(ResetUserPassword::class);

        RateLimiter::for('login', function (Request $request) {
            $throttleKey = Str::transliterate(Str::lower($request->input(Fortify::username())).'|'.$request->ip());

            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($throttleKey);
        });

        RateLimiter::for('two-factor', function (Request $request) {
            return Limit::perMinute(5)->by($request->session()->get('login.id'));
        });

        Fortify::loginView(function () {
            return view('auth.login');
        });
        Fortify::registerView(function () {
            return view('auth.register');
        });
        // Two factor Fortify
        Fortify::twoFactorChallengeView(function () {
            return view('auth.two-factor-challenge');
        });
        Fortify::resetPasswordView(function (Request $request) {
            return view('auth.reset-password', ['request' => $request]);
        });
        Fortify::verifyEmailView(function () {
            return view('auth.verify-email');
        });
        Fortify::confirmPasswordView(function () {
            return view('auth.confirm-password');
        });
    }
}
```

Any idea why it just doesnt redirect me to the 2fa challange view? I kinda have the feeling i have to set up the logic by myself but don't know where to start.

As i know now Breeze doesnt come with 2fa functionality but fortify should handle these redirects by itself no? Well it doesn#t as it seems and i tried to solve this by following this thread but with no success: https://github.com/laravel/fortify/issues/305